# SignalR is not loading data from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am trying to write something to a database and have it appear in real-time without refreshing the page. Writing to the database works, even displaying the information the normal way works, IE `_dbcontext.TableName.ToList();` But the signalR one doesn't do anything. I'm trying to figure out why but I have had no luck. Also i put the javascript file in the shared layout and not directly in the viewpage

startup:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(o => {

                o.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
            
            });
            services.AddDbContext<PostDBContext>(options => {

                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("PostDbContextConnection"));
                options.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);


            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapHub<SignalHub>("/SignalHub");
            });
        }
    }
}
```

controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR.Controllers
{
    public class PostController : Controller
    {
        private readonly PostDBContext _pdb;
        private readonly IHubContext<SignalHub> _signal;

        public PostController(PostDBContext pdb, IHubContext<SignalHub> signal)
        {
            _pdb = pdb;
            _signal = signal;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult GetViewPost()
        {
            var res = _pdb.Posts.ToList();
            return Ok(res);
        }
        public IActionResult ViewPost()
        {
            var res = _pdb.Posts.ToList();
            return View(res);
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task <IActionResult> ViewPost(Posts pm)
        {
            var res = _pdb.Posts.ToList();
            string text = pm.textPost;
            _pdb.Posts.Add(pm);
            await _pdb.SaveChangesAsync();
            await _signal.Clients.All.SendAsync("LoadData");

            return View(res);
        }
    }
}
```

signal hub:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR
{
    public class SignalHub : Hub 
    {
    }
}
```

model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Social_Media_Post_Realtime_SignalR.Models
{
    public class Posts
    {
        [Key]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string textPost { get; set; }

    }
}
```

view:

```
@model List<Posts>

<!--user post tweet start-->
<div class="contain" align="center" style="padding: 10px; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 0px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;  box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888;">
    <div class="input-group mb-3" style="margin-top:10px;">
        <form method="post" asp-controller="Post" asp-action="viewpost">
            <input name="textPost" class="form-control"  placeholder="Say something....." value="" />
            <span validation-for="textPost" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input type="submit" value="Post" class="btn" id="button-addon2" style="background-color: #1976d2; color: white;"/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<!--user post tweet end-->

<div id="postBody"></div>
```

javascript:

```
$(() => {

    LoadPost();
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/SignalHub").build();
    connection.start();
    connection.on("LoadData", function () {

        LoadPost();
    })
    LoadPost();

    function LoadPost() {

        $.ajax({

            url: 'Post/GetViewPost',
            method: 'GET',
            success: (result) => {
                $.each(result, (k, v) => {

                    <div class="contain" style="padding: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888; ">

                        <img src="/mad.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="55" height="55" style="margin-left: -15px; margin-right: 10px; border-radius: 50%; float: left;"/>
                            <div class=" comment" style="text-indent: 0px; text-indent: 0px;">
                                <h8 style="text-align: left; "><strong>bank</strong> @@bank</h8>
                                <br />
                                <p1 style=" overflow:hidden;"> <small>${v.textPost} </small></p1>

                            </div>
                            <div class="icons" style="margin-bottom: -40px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
                                <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text" style="margin-right: 150px;"></i>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-retweet" style="margin-right: 150px"></i>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart" style="margin-right: 50px;"></i>
                            </div>
                    </div>

                })
                $("#postBody").html();
            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });









        //document.write("<h1>Hello member</h1>");
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out I had a couple of things wrong. in the `url:` i forgot to add a backslash /, and i changed how the javascript read HTML

```
$(() => {

    
    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/SignalHub").build();
    connection.start();
    connection.on("LoadData", function () {

        LoadPost();
    })
    LoadPost();

    function LoadPost() {

        var pl = '';

        $.ajax({

            url: '/Post/GetViewPost',
            method: 'GET',
            success: (result) => {
                $.each(result, (k, v) => {

                    pl += `<div class="contain" style="padding: 30px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 50px; margin-top: 10px; border: 1px solid #CDCDCD; box-shadow: 5px 1px 10px #888888; ">

                        <img src="/mad.jpg" alt="Girl in a jacket" width="55" height="55" style="margin-left: -15px; margin-right: 10px; border-radius: 50%; float: left;"/>
                            <div class=" comment" style="text-indent: 0px; text-indent: 0px;">
                                <h8 style="text-align: left; "><strong>bank</strong> @@bank</h8>
                                <br />
                                <p1 style=" overflow:hidden;"> <small>${v.textPost} </small></p1>

                            </div>
                            <div class="icons" style="margin-bottom: -40px; padding-top: 20px; text-align: center;">
                                <i class="bi bi-chat-right-text" style="margin-right: 150px;"></i>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-retweet" style="margin-right: 150px"></i>
                                <i class="fa-solid fa-heart" style="margin-right: 50px;"></i>
                            </div>
                    </div>`

                })
                $("#postBody").html(pl);
            },
            error: (error) => {
                console.log(error)
            }
        });









        
    }
})
```